# What can we use in alternative option of explode() in pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to run python script in which I am using explode() to split row into multiple rows but the condition is this we can use explode() in the higher version of pandas means pandas version should be greater than or equal to `'0.25.0'`

So in higher version of pandas explode() is working fine. I used below code:

```
columns = ['rule_id', 'applied_sql_function1', 'input_condition', 'input_value', 'and_or_not_oprtor', 'output_condition', 'priority_order','comb_fld_order']

df_main1 = (df_main1.set_index(['rule_id', 'applied_sql_function1', 'input_condition', 'input_value', 'and_or_not_oprtor', 'output_condition', 'priority_order']).apply(lambda x: x.astype(str).str.split(',').explode()).reset_index())
```

I am splitting `comb_fld_order` column.

I need some alternative solution so that new logic can give the same result like explode() in the lower version of pandas. Can someone please help me how to do this?

```
df1:

rule_id    priority_order    comb_fld_order   
R162       2.3               1
R162       2.3.1             1
R162       2.6               2
R162       2.6.1             2
R162       3.0.4             3.2,3.1,3
```

Expected Output:

```
df1:

rule_id    priority_order    comb_fld_order   
R162       2.3               1
R162       2.3.1             1
R162       2.6               2
R162       2.6.1             2
R162       3.0.4             3.2
R162       3.0.4             3.1
R162       3.0.4             3
```

Comment: Is possible add some data sample?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) after [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html), then remove last level of MultiIndex by first [`Series.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reset_index.html) and by second convert `Series` to `DataFrame`:

```
df_main1 = (df_main1.set_index(['rule_id','priority_order'])['comb_fld_order']
                    .astype(str)
                    .str.split(',', expand=True)
                    .stack()
                    .reset_index(level=-1, drop=True)
                    .reset_index(name='comb_fld_order')
            )

print (df_main1)
  rule_id priority_order comb_fld_order
0    R162            2.3              1
1    R162          2.3.1              1
2    R162            2.6              2
3    R162          2.6.1              2
4    R162          3.0.4            3.2
5    R162          3.0.4            3.1
6    R162          3.0.4              3
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try:

```
    df = df.set_index(['rule_id','priority_order']).comb_fld_order.apply(pd.Series).stack().reset_index(level=0).rename(columns={0:'comb_fld_order'}).reset_index()
    del df['level_1']
```

Hope this will work.

Comment: Please share sample data

Comment: please check ma'am

Comment: it works great! Excellent for arlier versions of pandas that do not support explode function.

Answer (score 1):

You could use itertools' [product](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) and [chain.from_iterable](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) to replicate `explode` :

```
from itertools import product, chain
outcome = chain.from_iterable(product([first], [second], last.split(',')) 
                              for first, second, last in df1.to_numpy()
                              )

pd.DataFrame(outcome, columns = df1.columns)

  rule_id   priority_order  comb_fld_order
0   R162    2.3              1
1   R162    2.3.1            1
2   R162    2.6              2
3   R162    2.6.1            2
4   R162    3.0.4            3.2
5   R162    3.0.4            3.1
6   R162    3.0.4            3
```